# Unable to run commans in magento 2

Tags: error, magento2.2.6, code-generation

I have tried to disable Magento_CatalogSearch in config.php.

After edited config.php, While trying to run commands throws the following error.

> "Source class
>   "\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\SearchCollection"
>   for
>   "Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\SearchCollectionFactory"
>   generation does not exist."

Can any one please resolve my problem

Comment: please remove once "var/generated/" autogenerated files for Magento and try to run a command again

Answer (score 1):

Please run below command once

```
rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/*
```

Then try to run deployment commands, because if you will try to disable module using `config.php` file then some auto generated class still available in generated directory that creates this issue. So please try to remove that or you can rename `generated` directory. Also please check permission of `var` and `generated` directory once, it should be 777.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I have renamed the generated folder and also removed var/view_preprocessed/* but still unable to clear cache

Comment: Still the error is throwing

Comment: Sorry I was forget to mention cache and page_cache directory here. @Jaisa

Comment: It's okay. @Kishan... Thanks for the timely help

Comment: You're welcome Buddy @Jaisa

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem as you said removed generated , But I forget to delete var/cache/*. After  that, I have run di: compile command and works fine